# Swift: Iterate through array and count Ints equal to 5

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift how would I iterate through the NSMutableArray of ints `var numbers = [4,5,5,4,3]` and count how many are equal to 5?

Comment: Just to remind you that `var numbers = [4,5,5,4,3]` is not of type `NSMutableArray`. Major difference is that it is a value type and not a reference to an object. Said that, I upvoted the @ Sebastian Dressler solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `reduce` for this:

```
let array = [4,5,5,4,3]
let fives = array.reduce(0, combine: { $0 + Int($1 == 5) })
```

Comment: Is this compatible with NSMutableArray?

Comment: Yes, with casting to a Swift array. Otherwise use a method profided by `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: That should have been "provided" ;)

Comment: I didn't know that you can use boolean literals in the constructor of Int, very classy, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Note that `Int($1 == 5)` invokes `init(_ number: NSNumber)` initializer defined in `Foundation`.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
numbers.filter {$0 == 5}.count
```

Comment: Where `a` equals the name of the array?

Comment: Yes, it is, I just didn't described it.